# Replace stylesheet with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, stylesheet

The replacement is done in real time - user clicks something, the style changes:

```
$('link#mystyle').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('link#mystyle').remove();

if(new_style){
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" id="mystyle" href="' 
                    + new_style +'.css" type="text/css" />');

}
```

The problem is that by default there is a inline style block after the stylesheet link:

```
<style>
  ...
</style>
```

And my code above will remove the original stylesheet, and append the new stylesheet after the style block, so the new stylesheet will override some rules from the style block.

I don't want that, so can I somehow append my new style in the same place, so the rules inside the new stylesheet are applied with the same priority as the initial stylesheet rules?

Comment: after appending the new CSS file, you could go back, grab the STYLE block, remove it, then re-append it. Seems hacky, though. I'm sure there's a better option.

Comment: You could just swap out the href param in the link tag. Do you need help doing that?

Comment: though i have not tried, $('link#mystyle').replaceWith($('<link rel="stylesheet" id="mystyle" href="' 
                    + new_style +'.css" type="text/css" />')), should work

Comment: Yeah I was going to ask if just changing the href would work: `$("#mystyle").attr("href", new_style);`

Comment: Changing href fails in IE after doing it 3-4 times. It appears it's a memory issue with this browser..

Comment: Depending on how many rules your stylesheet has (and it sounds like a lot), the initial parsing of the DOM to match each rule is one of the most expensive things a browser does. By completely removing and re-adding a new stylesheet you're suffering this performance hit multiple times. That would explain your memory issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kroehre is right, but if you insist on doing it your way there is the http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ method.

```
$('link#mystyle').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" id="mystyle" href="' 
                + new_style +'.css" type="text/css" />');
```

should do what you want.

Comment: I don't think this would be any better than just changing the href attr though would it?

Comment: Changing href messes up the site in IE 9, but your solution appears to work.

Answer (score 6):

A better solution would be to format your css to vary based on a high level class or id on the body tag:

```
/*Style 1*/
body.style1 h1{...}
body.style1 ...

/*Style 2*/
body.style2 h1{...}
body.style2 ...
```

Then, all you have to do is change the class on the body tag:

```
$('#something-to-click').click(function(){
  ($('body').hasClass('style1')){
    $('body').addClass('style2').removeClass('style1');
  }else{    
    $('body').addClass('style1').removeClass('style2');
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you're approaching your css rules... any rules that are the same wouldn't need to be duplicated, only the specific rules that are different would need to be specifically assigned to the applicable class variation

Comment: these css files represent different site designs. besides the layout dimension definitions (which is only about 15-20 lines of code), everything is different

Comment: Perhaps vary the stylesheet using a url parameter and make the change server-side? Better to resolve a simple if statement at the server than push the limits of your users' browsers.